# MySQL Calculate 2 date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I created a table with 2 columns to store `startDate` and `endDate`.

**For example:**

```
ID startDate  endDate
1  2011-04-19 2011-04-21
```

I want to calculate the difference of these two days and return "3". Is it possible to calculate it using SQL?

Comment: Yes. It's entirely possible to calculate by using SQL, as explained in myriad sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`DATEDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) for this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(endDate, startDate) + 1
FROM mytable
```

**Note:** You have to add 1 so as get `startDate` included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use Datediff FUNCTION

```
select datediff(enddate, startdate) + 1 from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the DATEDIFF() function in MySQL that does exactly that.
SELECT DATEDIFF(endDate, startDate) will return the difference (which is 2, not 3)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATEDIFF` function.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(endDate,startDate)+1 AS Difference
FROM yourtable
```

Output

```
Difference
3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9373ec/3/0

More reading here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff.